# Write each file name and content to another file in C

Tags: c, file, strcat

So I'm sort of new to C language, and I'm trying to create a .dat file from other files (like some archiving program). I'm using arguements to specify the files in command line I want to write to my .dat file, and the **pack** function I wrote seems to be working.

The problem is, I want to create an **unpack** function too. I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to do this, but I want to copy the argument (the name of the file I want to pack) to it's content, so later, in my unpack function I could search for it inside the .dat file and unpack it.

I'm using this code to write the files to the .dat:

```
if(!wanttoArchive){
                    printf("Cannot open %s file\n",argv[i]);
                } else {
                    fseek(wanttoArchive, 0L, SEEK_END); 
                    pos = ftell(wanttoArchive);
                    fseek(wanttoArchive, 0L, SEEK_SET); 
                    while (pos--){
                        ch = fgetc(wanttoArchive); 
                        fputc(ch, archived);
                    }
                }
```

I wanted to use strcat inside the fputc, put it's not working.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using string operations you should use offsets. Write the length of the file you want to write on the begining so you know when the file will end and you can go to the next file.

Comment: if you want to be able to unpack the files, later, then there needs to be some recognizable token in the packed file that the unpacker can search for, recognize as the beginning of a file.  As suggested by @Eun, I would also keep the size of the file along with the name of the file.  The posted code does nothing by copy a file, byte by byte.  with no information about file start, length, name

Comment: Yeah I know, I just copied that part where I copy the file(s). I also tought the same thing, but besides fputc, is there any function which can write to the file? So I can add something the unpack can recognize. Or how'd you add the token to the beginning of each file? (Sorry if I write something wrong, english is not my native language, and also sorry if I ask stupid questions)